# change content attribute of css class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a CSS

```
   .counter{
   span{display: none;}
   &:before{
   content: "Bookmark";
}
}



   <div class="counter fl" id="add_counter" ></div>
```

i want a JQuery code that change content attribute of CSS from bookmark to bookmarked

Comment: IS ur HTML correct? I doubt it,please create fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another class that has content set to bookmarked:

```
$('.counter').addClass('bookmarked');
```

**CSS:**

```
.bookmarked{
    content: "Bookmarked";
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sY2JK/)**

Comment: Can u please give fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9kyg7/ doesn't works. Correct me

Comment: Sir , It does not work ,spot any issue?

Comment: I was updating the answer.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar , hello but u added class. OP wanted to add content attribute

Comment: @PratikJoshi: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/1719752

Comment: U mean PurpleDroid answer is wrong?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: i thought same in the beginning. but its not going to work for psuedo elements.